# How to pass an instance of a form to another form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form called `form1` with controls which are created during run-time.

When I press a button on the Form another Form loads called `combat` and `form1` is hidden so that only 1 form (`combat`) is visible.

When I press a button on `combat` I want my `form1` form the be shown. However I can't access it.

Here is what I've tried:

```
 private void combatBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form combat = new Combat(this);
        this.Hide();
        combat.Show();

    }

public partial class Combat : Form
 {

    public Combat(Form form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form.Show();


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a rule, you don't want to be doing this.  You shouldn't ever need to pass a parent form to it's child form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class Combat : Form
{

    private form1 form;    // Or whatever class you form1 is supposed to be

    public Combat(Form form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form = form;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the parent form in a field so that you can access it outside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not advisable to pass an instance of a parent form to a child.  In this case (as is often true) the code is actually simpler when you don't:

```
private void combatBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form combat = new Combat();
    this.Hide();
    combat.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

If you need to show the parent form before the child form is closed then you can do so through events:

in `Combat` add:

```
public event Action MyEvent; //TODO rename to a meaningful name
```

Fire the event in the button click handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyEvent();
}
```

And then have your main form add a handler to the event:

```
private void combatBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Combat combat = new Combat();
    this.Hide();
    combat.MyEvent += () => this.Show();
    combat.Show();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question that showing the `Combat` dialog modally is what they are trying to achieve. Their code for showing the parent doesn't close the child and it isn't clear that they wanted to.

Comment: @MattBurland Added another solution, should he need to show the main form before the child form is closed.

Comment: +1, a good solution. I agree that passing around references to forms is probably best avoided. Better to avoid tight coupling.